# Working with lib files in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, static-libraries

I created a lib file called `StackExample.lib`. There are functions and objects described in `Stack.hpp` and `Example.hpp`.

I want to have an easy time importing my library so I wrote another file called `StackExample.hpp`.

This file contains:

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib, "StackExample.lib")

#include "Stack.hpp"
#include "Example.hpp"
```

Unfortunately I can no longer compile `StackExample.lib` because it can not import itself.

Is there a precompiler statement that I can use so that all importing programs load the lib but my lib would ignore that line?

Comment: Use a preprocessor macro defined only in the `StackExample.lib` project (use the settings of the project to define) and #ifndef  to conditionally add `#pragma comment(lib, "StackExample.lib")` only when you are using the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#ifndef __STACK_EXAMPLE_INTERNAL
#pragma comment(lib, "StackExample.lib")
#endif
```

and then right click on your library project, select Properties => Configuration Properties => C/C++ => Preprocessor

Add __STACK_EXAMPLE_INTERNAL into "Preprocessor Definitions".

This way your library will define this definition and client's (hopefully) not.